# A function stops being inline. Any explanation?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, stack, inline

I have a code of the following structure:

```c
void foo1(uint32_t *num_failures)
{
   ...
}

void foo2(uint32_t *num_failures)
{
   ...
}

void foo3(uint32_t *num_failures)
{
   ...
}

void test()
{
   uint32_t num_failures = 0;
   foo1(&num_failures);
   foo2(&num_failures);
   foo3(&num_failures);
}
```

Now, what I did was add the following instruction to **foo1()**:

```c
void foo1(uint32_t *num_failures)
{
   ...
   (*num_failures)++;
}
```

And suddenly I see that stack size printed from inside **foo2()** is larger by 36 bytes.

I did an objdump and greped for <symbols>. Yielding the following:

Before the change:

```
...
00004e08 <test>:
```

After the change:

```
...
00004e08 <foo2>:
00005588 <test>:
```

So I guess the function foo2 stopped being inline.

1. Am I correct?
2. Any explanation why that happened?
3. What happened to foo3() after the change? Did it become inline inside **foo2()** or inside **test()**?

Not sure if required: I'm using gcc for arc processor.

Comment: Thanks Yu, didn't know it was wrong.

Comment: Guess: The (*num_failures) access requires local variable. Either the number of registers or stack size available for 'test()' is exceeded, hence causing the compiler to split it in the next available point, which is foo2().

Comment: I think inline is a hint to the compiler which may choose to ignore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After learning some more on the subject, and seeing some lectures by Chandler Caruth, I would say the compiler decides almost indeterministicly where to inline the code. Especially when not givinig it any 'inline' hints, as in my case.